# accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier not finishing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, twitter, social-framework

I'm attempting to access Twitter accounts, but this code is halting on the line `accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier`.

My code looks like this, i'm running iOS 6:

```
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
#import <Social/Social.h>
#import <Twitter/Twitter.h>

NSLog(@"1");
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
NSLog(@"2");
ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
NSLog(@"3");
[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"5");

}];
NSLog(@"4");
```

I get NSLogs 1 and 2, which means the accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier line isn't returning. I've tried running this both on the main thread and in a background thread, to no avail.

Comment: what is this? Please elaborate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that you've forgotten to add Accounts.framework to your project.
(This solved the same problem for me)